# Is there any shortcut/command available to skip karma tests? like -DskipTests for Maven

Tags: maven, npm, web-applications, karma-jasmine

I have created Maven Web application and I generally use

```
mvn clean install
```

So it execute `npm install` command as its one of the execution goal and then it run karma tests
So my question is, is there any shortcut or command available to skip karma tests conditionally?
Like we have -DskipTests for Maven project to skip tests.

Off course we can simply remove the `npm run test` from the `package.json` file but I want to skip tests using command.

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>web/app</workingDirectory>
                        <installDirectory>build</installDirectory>
                        <arguments>install
                            --registry=${npm.registry}
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am using the `frontend-maven-plugin` I had to add below execution to plugin.

```
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>javascript tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>karma</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

After that, just using `-DskipTest` build argument able to skip karma tests.

`mvn clean install -DskipTests`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define a system property `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to skip the unit test.

   ```
   mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
   ```
2. Define properties in pom.xml

   ```
   <properties>
       <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
   </properties>
   ```
3. Use `-DskipTests` in surefire plugin

   ```
   mvn package -DskipTests
   ```
4. Define surefire plugin in pox.xml

   ```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

Comment: The above command will skip the JUnit tests and not the karma tests. I want to skip karma tests using the command.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

-DskipTests will skip the Karma tests. Please refer to the following snippet available at https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin
"Skipping tests: If you run maven with the -DskipTests flag, karma tests will be skipped."

So, Front end test cases are getting executed under "frontend-maven-plugin" which seems to recognize only -DskipTests to skip test cases execution unlike "maven-surefire-plugin" which recognizes both "-DskipTests" as well as "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" command parameters. So, if we use -DskipTests rather -Dmaven.test.skip=true command parameters, both backend as well as front end test cases get skipped.

This is what has been tested locally using -DskipTests
[Skip FE Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkV4x.png)

Comment: The above command will skip the JUnit tests and not the karma tests. I want to skip karma tests using the command.

Comment: @GaneshThorat I've edited my response to be more elaborative. Please refer that,